# getJSON in getson

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I have two JSON-Datas looking like that:

```
[{
  "productId": "1",
  "name": "RX7048",
  "imageUrl": "http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image",
  "description": "Modern design.",
  "price": "229.95",
  "manufacturerId": "1"
}, {
  "productId": "2",
  "name": "RB 2132 52 New Wayfarer",
  "imageUrl": "http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image",
  "description": "Best Seller",
  "price": "129.95",
  "manufacturerId": "1"
}, {
  ...
}]
```

and

```
{
  "1": {
    "manufacturerId": "1",
    "name": "Ray-Ban",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "website": ""
  },
  "2": {
    "manufacturerId": "2",
    ...
  }
}
```

I am trying to display them in a HTML website like that:

```
function getAllProducts() {
  $.getJSON('http://meyecare.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products', function(data) {
    var len = data.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      //get the name of the Manufacturer by Manufact.-Id         
      var w = $.getJSON('http://meyecare.herokuapp.com/api/v1/manufacturers/' + data[i].manufacturerId);

      $('#products').append("<tr><td class='name'>" + data[i].name +
                            "</td><td><img class='prodImg' src='" + 
                            data[i].imageUrl +  "'/>"+
                            "<td class='manus'>" + w.name + "</td>"+
                            "<td class='descr'>" + data[i].description+
                            "</td>" +
                            "<td>$ " + data[i].price+
                            "</td><td><span class='btn' prodId='" +
                            data[i].productId + "'>Buy me</span></td></tr>");
    }        
  });
}
```

It is showing me the Table with the correct Products in the correct Columns and Rows, but the column that tries to join the Manufacturers-Name shows "[object Object]" instead of the Manufacturername.

I cannot find the mistake, can anyone help me please..?

Comment: for some reason it shows me now "undefined" instead of "Object object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your "Manufacturers-Name" column is the `td` with `manus` class. If that's the case, then I assume the question is why `w.name` does not display correctly.

[`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is asynchronous. It returns a promise instead of the actual API response. So `w` in this case is a promise, not the manufacturer data.

You need to use `$.getJSON` the way you used it for the first time (by passing in `success` callback).

Comment: I tried to follow your suggest as I did the followig:function getAllProducts() {
  $.getJSON('productsJSON', function(data) {
    var len = data.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
  $.getJSON('manufaJSON/' + data[i].name, function(mansData) {

Comment: But the result is that is shows me nothing, neither ne ManufacturersName nor the table

Comment: What is the response of `$getJSON('manufaJSON/theId')`? I think the endpoint just returns a list of manufacturers instead of individual of them.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EmnQR1Nq7y1PeiLa2LoB?p=preview) that demonstrates my suggestion above.